# How to get privacy policy contents through api in bigcommerce to show in mobile version of my bigcommerce store in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bigcommerce

We are developing an eCommerce app for pets using BigCommerce as our engine and their api's. We have created our privacy and security policy contents by creating a page for in the admin panel.

Now we want to show the privacy policy contents in the mobile app using BigCommerce api, we went through the documentation also but unfortunately we could not find any relevant api for the same. Is there any way to show the latest privacy policy contents every time by using their api or any other source.

Can any one please guide us the correct way to achieve it? Or show us any other custom way by which we can get these contents by URL so that we can consume the same in our app. Your little help is very much appreciated to get through this issue. Thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the page details using the Pages API:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/marketing/store-content-api/pages/getallpages